# Is there a way I can lock a file from being modified on the git master branch?

Tags: git

I have a config file in my source code on the master branch that shouldn't be modified by others.

Is there a way I can put a rule/lock so that even if others try to change this file and push the change, it won't allow them to do it?

Example file: src/test/resources/config/Environment.xml

Example scenario for some developer:

```
vi src/test/resources/config/Environment.xml
git add src/test/resources/config/Environment.xml
git commit -a
git push origin master
```

Desired Message: Something like : "Error: Locked file Environment.xml cannot be modified."

Comment: Not built-in to Git, but many Git hosters like GitHub allow you to protect named branches. You can also add an existing file’s path to your gitignore to make it harder to accidentally commit changes to it.

Comment: Environment configuration shouldn't be committed to source control.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this file is important for production and no one is supposed to change it then you should exclude it from the repository using .gitignore ..
You should add this file to your production repository and .gitignore will ensure that it is always untouched and untracked. 
There is no way to prevent writing to a remote file via git.

Comment: Note that this doesn't block editing and committing the changes to a file that is already committed.

Comment: Well the idea is to post this file to its end-destination manually and make sure that the file isn't in the repository and is in the .gitignore locally.
You can also ignore the file after it's been commited. It will be excluded with the following push and removed from the remote repository

Comment: "It will be excluded with the following push and removed from the remote repository" If you also, `git rm` the file, then yes, that is true.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i misunderstood what you meant. you mean remove the file from tracking using git rm --cached on top of adding it to .gitignore. I am not sure if that is necessary but if you say so, i remember doing it before to a vendor folder and all it took is just ignoring it so..

Comment: I mean removing it from tracking entirely: `git rm <file name>` and then `git commit`. This is the only way to remove the file from the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a git hook, e.g. the pre-commit or the pre-receive hook.

See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks